# In Angular material I want to calculate two mat-cell input value and show it in another mat-cell (in Dynamically added Columns)

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table, dynamic-tables

I have created a mat-table in which Columns are dynamically added. Now I want to run the operation in my two columns **(Unit Price * Qty/Rolls)** and show results on Amount columns. In footer
I want to show the total Qty/Rolls and amount.
here is What I have done soo far:
[stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiselect-with-dynamic-columns-tp7vjl?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/datatable/datatable.component.ts)

My HTML Code

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="rows" matSort matSortActive="symbol" matSortDirection="asc">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index;">

    <span *ngIf="i === 0 ">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        SN
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let sn=index">
        {{sn+1}}
      </mat-cell>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="i !== 0 && i<colLenght-3">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        {{column | fieldToDisplay}}
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;">
        {{element[column]}}
      </mat-cell>

    </span>
    <span *ngIf="i !== 0 && i>=colLenght-1">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        {{column | fieldToDisplay}}
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
          <input matInput placeholder [value]="element[column]" [(ngModel)]="element[column]">
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-cell>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="i !== 0 && i>=colLenght-2">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        {{column | fieldToDisplay}}
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
          <input matInput placeholder [value]="element[column]" (change)="calculate(i)" [(ngModel)]="element[column]">
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-cell>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="i !== 0 && i>=colLenght-3">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        {{column | fieldToDisplay}}
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
          <input matInput placeholder [value]="element[column]" (change)="calculate(i)" [(ngModel)]="element[column]">
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-cell>
    </span>

  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns; sticky: true;"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>

<button id="hide" add mat-raised-button color="accent">Get Checked Items</button>
```

Ts Code:

```
  @Input()
  public content: any;
  colLenght: number;
  public rows = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  public columns = [];
  dataSource = [
    {
      SalesOrderId_Hide: 11,
      ItemId: 11,
      SlNo: 1,
      'Item Name': 'Barcode Label',
      'Description Of Goods': '4"X 3" Type: Mat Fasoin',
      'Qty/Rolls': 5,
      'Unit Price': 5,
      Amount: 9
    }
  
  ];


  private updateRows(): void {
    this.rows = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.content);
    
  }

  private updateColumns(): void {
    debugger;

    for (const column of Object.keys(this.content[0])) {
      this.columns.push(column);
    }
    this.colLenght = this.columns.length;
  }

  private updateTable(): void {
    if (this.content) {
      this.updateRows();
      this.updateColumns();
    }
  }

  public showFamilies(): void {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.content = this.dataSource;
    this.updateTable();
  }

  calculate(i) {
    console.log(i);
  }
  constructor() {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-multiple-header-footer) from Angular Material, you can set your **calculate** formula in your *ts* file to:

```js
calculate(i: number) {
    return this.dataSource[i].Amount * this.dataSource[i].UnitPrice
  }
```

Then in your *html* file, you can interpolate it:

```html
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
          <input matInput>{{calculate(i)}}
        </mat-form-field>
    </mat-cell>
```

Note that I did need to change `'Unit Price'` to `UnitPrice`.

**EDIT**
On the assumption that the data under `"Qty/Rolls"` and `"Unit Price"` will always be the basis for your calculation, I passed the full `element`'s  contents to `calculate`:

```html
<span *ngIf="i !== 0 && i>=colLenght-1">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        {{column | fieldToDisplay}}
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
          <input matInput placeholder [value]="element[column]" [(ngModel)]="element[column]"> {{calculate(element)}}<!--Here-->
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-cell>
    </span>
```

And then in the *ts* file, calculated as follows:

```js
calculate(el: any) {
    if (el["Qty/Rolls"] && el["Unit Price"]) {
      var a: number = el["Qty/Rolls"];
      var b: number = el["Unit Price"];
      var c: number = a * b;
      console.log("Amount: "+c);//or: return c
    }
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately calculate(i: number) here i returning index of columns  in need the index  of row number  to access this.dataSource[i].UnitPrice

Comment: By the way, when testing I changed the sample prices to different values. Having all data with the same quantities and prices made it hard to determine whether the formula was processing correctly.

Comment: it's working  how it's not updating my data source therefore I cant get the updated value

Comment: I probably do not understand your statement, but here is a try: your current data source is static JSON. If you change your data source to an observable stream, you will see the data get updated dynamically. As per the [api](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) doc: *When providing an Observable stream, the table will trigger an update automatically when the stream emits a new array of data.* So you may need to look at [creating Observable stream](https://angular.io/guide/observables).